# Solicitud de transferencia de stock SAP en Java

Tags: java, c#, whatsapp-web

no se si alguno ya desarrollo una solicitud de transferencia de stock de SAP con el api DI 9.3 en java, actualmente tengo el siguiente fragmento de codigo:

```
        IStockTransfer doc = SBOCOMUtil.newStockTransfer(csap.getMyCompany());
        
        
        doc.setFromWarehouse("B80");
        doc.setToWarehouse("B90");
        doc.setComments("Una transferencia muy grande");
        doc.setDocDate(new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        doc.setCardCode("CL000586");        
    doc.setDocObjectCode(SBOCOMConstants.BoObjectTypes_StockTransfer_oInventoryTransferRequest);
        
        
// Agregar una línea al documento
        doc.getLines().setItemCode("1-A-800003");
        doc.getLines().setWarehouseCode("B90");
        doc.getLines().setFromWarehouseCode("B01");
        doc.getLines().setQuantity(1.0);
        doc.getLines().add();
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me da el error:
Error al ingresar: No es posible añadir una línea sin la selección completa de los números de serie/lote

Cuando yo estoy tratando de hacer una solicitud no una transferencia en si.

Homologamente en C# hice el siguiente:

```
SAPbobsCOM.StockTransfer doc = (SAPbobsCOM.StockTransfer)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oInventoryTransferRequest);

                doc.FromWarehouse = "B01";
                doc.ToWarehouse = "B90";
                doc.Comments = "LAN TEST for draft";
                doc.DocDate = DateTime.Now;
                doc.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_TIPOSOLICITUD").Value = "COM";
                doc.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_SOLICITANTE").Value = 8;
                doc.CardCode = "CL000586";
                doc.DocObjectCode = SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oInventoryTransferRequest; //  oStockTransfer;

 

                doc.Lines.ItemCode = "1-A-800003";
                doc.Lines.WarehouseCode = "B90";
                doc.Lines.FromWarehouseCode = "B01";
                doc.Lines.Quantity = 1.0;
                doc.Lines.Add();
```

Y aca si me permite hacer la solicitud.

En resumen, lo que deseo lograr es enviar la solicitud de transferencia pero desde Java, donde actualmente me da el error comentado.

Answer (score 0):

En C#, para crear un borrador, lo declaras como tipo `oDrafts` y luego le asignas el código correspondiente; en este caso `oInventoryTransferRequest`.

```
SAPbobsCOM.Documents doc = (SAPbobsCOM.Documents)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oDrafts);
doc.DocObjectCode = SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oInventoryTransferRequest;
```

El error `No es posible añadir una línea sin la selección completa de los números de serie/lote` es porque el artículo que estás usando tiene la configración de ser de tipo serie, por lo cual debes de agregar

```
doc.Lines.SerialNumbers.SystemSerialNumber = "1" // ejemplo
```

En el código de Java que muestras, estás ingresando un documento ya final, no borrador.

Comment: En verdad en se esta configurando como una stock request en C#
doc.DocObjectCode = SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oInventoryTransferRequest; //  oStockTransfer; 

Tambien en Java
doc.setDocObjectCode(SBOCOMConstants.BoObjectTypes_StockTransfer_oInventoryTransferRequest);

en verdad no entiendo, por que desde C# se va pero en Java no, y el problema es que el proceso completo esta en Java